# Is there a better way to populate a listView in a fragment while getting the data with volley?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-volley, android-adapter

I'm doing an exercise where I have to fetch a JSONArray object from a server via Volley library. And then populate a listView with that data. I've done it but I think there must be a better way. The only way I could come up to to make it work was setting the adapter inside the onResponse method of the JSONArrayRequest that I send to volley.

Is it possible to set the adapter inside the onCreateView method of the fragment?

Here is my code:

```
public class UserListFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String USERS_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/users.json";
    public static final String TAG = UserListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private VolleyManager volleyManager;
    private List<User> users;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_list, null);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        Button obtain_data_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.user_list_obtain_btn);
        obtain_data_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getUsersListData();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void getUsersListData() {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRqst = new JsonArrayRequest(
                USERS_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        users = parseUserList(response.toString());
                        listView.setAdapter(new UsersAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, users));
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
                }
                }
        );

        volleyManager = VolleyManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        volleyManager.addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRqst);
    }

    /**
     * Parses a users json array into a users list.
     *
     * @param jsonArray
     *
     * @return Users list
     */
    private List<User> parseUserList(String jsonArray) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // Declares the list type
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();

        List<User> userList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, listType);

        return userList;
    }

    private class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

        public UsersAdapter(Context context, int itemResourceId) {
            super(context, itemResourceId);
        }

        public UsersAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<User> users) {
            super(context, resource, users);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View listItemView = convertView;

            if (listItemView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
                layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                listItemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            User user = getItem(position);

            TextView userNameTV = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.userName_userList);
            TextView userLastNameTV = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.userLastName_userList);
            TextView userAgeTV = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.userAge_userList);

            userNameTV.setText(user.getName());
            userLastNameTV.setText(user.getLastName());
            userAgeTV.setText(Integer.toString(user.getAge()));

            return listItemView;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way.  Create a reference to your Adapter as a member variable of the Fragment, this allows you to call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) after the data comes in.

One thing to note, you can't change the reference of your data source, which is the `users` List.  So, when the data comes in, use [`addAll()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20E%3E)) to add the data without re-assigning the data source reference.

Your code should be something like this:

```
public class UserListFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String USERS_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/users.json";
    public static final String TAG = UserListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private VolleyManager volleyManager;
    private List<User> users;

    UsersAdapter adapter; //added

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_list, null);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        //added:
        adapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, users);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        Button obtain_data_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.user_list_obtain_btn);
        obtain_data_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getUsersListData();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void getUsersListData() {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRqst = new JsonArrayRequest(
                USERS_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //modified:
                        users.addAll(parseUserList(response.toString()));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
                }
                }
        );

        volleyManager = VolleyManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        volleyManager.addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRqst);
    }

    //.........
```

Comment: I'm getting an error. **FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference. at com.volleytest.UserListFragment.onCreateView(UserListFragment.java:59)** That would be the line where I set the adapter.

Comment: I solved it. I had to initialize users. Thank you Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I set my adapter to an ExpandableListView in my onCreateView of my fragment in my current project.  You should have no problems doing that.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View parentThis = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_exlv, container, false);


      exlvTabHistory = (ExpandableListView)parentThis.findViewById(R.id.exlvTabHistory);
      exlvTabHistory.setAdapter(setupEXLVAdapter());
    }
```